# React native app go to blank page after published

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I published an app in the app store, the app was made in react native.
Everything in the app works fine except for a page, when i click to a button to navigate to other page using react navigation i can see the page for 0.5 seconds then i get a blank page.
The app is published in the app store and this happens when i use the real app download from the store, when i use the local app with expo this doesn’t happen and i have no error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H279u.png)

This is a screen of the blank page

Apologies if my english is bad hope someone can solve this, happy to answer to questions.

Comment: Please add some code. And did it work when you build it local for production?

Comment: Hi, adding code soon, anyway this doesn’t work work only in 1 page while i have about 10/12 pages

Answer (score 0):

In this case -

1. the First check is all dynamic value set states are correct.
2. check the paths of all import libraries and components.
3. Check library one by one is supported or not
4. Check UI by commenting one by one.
5. Check all the functions where the value is setting state properly or not